# AXIOS returning an empty array on ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, vue.js

I am trying to retrieve an array using axios to do the ajax request, but the result is always empty. Funny is that same request works just fine with `artisan tinker`!

Let's see some code:

route/web.php file

```
Route::get('/trocaCarros/{id}', 'VitrineController@trocaCarros')->name('trocaCarros');
```

The Vuejs method:

```
methods: {
umaMarca() {
// alert(marca.value);
axios.get('/trocaCarros/' + marca.value).then(response => this.vitrine = response.data);
  }
```

The VitrineController.php

```
public function trocaCarros(Request $request)
{
$marca = $request->id;
$umaMarcaModelo = Modelo::where('marca_id','=', $marca);
return response()->json($umaMarcaModelo);
}
```

The browser response is:

```
{}
```

But, when I did it at the Tinker:

```
Psy Shell v0.8.11 (PHP 7.1.6 — cli) by Justin Hileman
$marca = 212
=> 212
```

Then...

```
$modelo = App\Modelo::where('marca_id','=', $marca)->get();
```

It returns 6 results, as I have in database, like:

```
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#994
 all: [
   App\Modelo {#995
     id: 880011,
     descricao: "Accord",
     marca_id: "212",
     categoria_id: "1",
     ativo: 1,
     created_at: "2017-08-03 18:35:19",
     updated_at: "2017-08-03 19:41:36",
   },
   App\Modelo {#996
     id: 880012,
     descricao: "City",
     marca_id: "212",
     categoria_id: "1",
     ativo: 1,
     created_at: "2017-08-03 18:47:26",
     updated_at: "2017-08-03 18:47:26",
   },
```

... and more 4 others

Does anyone know what I missed?

Comment: Forgot the `->get()` in the first one?

Comment: Yes, i Forgot. Thakns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to get the param from the url in your controller.
update your The VitrineController.php like blow.

```
public function trocaCarros($id, Request $request)
{
    $marca = $id;
    $umaMarcaModelo = Modelo::where('marca_id', $marca)->get();
    return response()->json($umaMarcaModelo);
}
```

Comment: OK, now I want to render the result on a DIV. I know how to do it using jQuery, but how AXIOS handles that?

Answer (score 0):

When axios, you can get data by using:

```
axios.post(url,params)
.then(function(response) {
   // response.data contains the data
}).catch(function(error) {

});
```